# Is it possible to change status bar height / y position?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I've seen an app wherein they can dynamically adjust their status bar height/y-position based on scroll-position.

Here is a sample gif: https://gyazo.com/ec8e3fa336098305e6a5aedc68118789

Here is what I got

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
   return isStatusBarHidden
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
   if !isStatusBarHidden {
       return UIStatusBarAnimation.fade
   } else {
       return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
   }
}


func changeStatusBarStatus(status: Bool) {
   isStatusBarHidden = status
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
       self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
   })
}
```

Comment: You can hide `StatusBar` and use a `UIView` for that purpose and it will be more convenient and accessible in use

Comment: There is a native feature also " navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true" . But I am not sure if it will give you the same effect. Create a custom nav bar by using a view , add height constraint to this view. Implement the scrollViewDidScroll method and change the height constraint of the nav bar View based on scrollView contentOffset.y

Comment: @NayanDave, do you mean create a custom status bar? Is it possible?

Comment: @Help I think hidesBarsOnSwipe only hides the navbar rather than the status bar.

Comment: yes , you're right about @Help's suggestion it will only hide `navigationbar` not `statusbar`.....AND also yes, it's possible to create custom status bar...I'm writing the answer for it , please look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TO CREATE CUSTOM `StatusBar`**

- Firstly Hide your Default `statusBar` for the entire app by adding YES/TRUE in `Status bar is initially hidden` in the `info.plist`

  This will hide `StatusBar` from the app unless you add programatically re-show it.
- Then add a `UIView` in your `ViewController` and give it TOP, LEFT & RIGHT `constraint` (0,0,0) with reference to `View`(not with reference to `Safe Area`)
- Then Give it DOWN or BOTTOM `constraint` 0 with reference to your Main working `UIView`

**See, I've created a bottom view like that in my app (You just have to reverse this `constraint` as you are creating `StatusBar`)**

[image]

(Note:If you can't see that `UIView` then use *View As iPhone 10 or 11 Series* in which you can clearly distinguish it from your other `UIView`)